# AngularJS ngRepeat directive does not have compile option

Tags: angularjs

I find the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngRepeat.js) of ngRepeat does not have `compile` option mentioned in the guide of [HTML Compiler](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler).

I'm puzzled about this....

Who can tell me why...

Comment: Miško Hevery, Igor Minár and Vojta Jína would probably know the best...

Comment: It has a link function, which is the result of the compile that happens on all directives.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### `ngRepeat` has a **transclude** option.

- When using transclude , `$compile` compiles the transcluded element, and then provide a `childTranscludeFn` function to the linking function of the directive as the fifth argument (or $transclude in a directive's controller)
- This function is used to create multiple clones of the same compiled template.
- It is only compiled once when it's being transcluded.

#### A small code fragment from [compile.js source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js):

```
if (directiveValue = directive.transclude) {

  // some code

  if (directiveValue == 'element') {

    // some code

    childTranscludeFn = compile($template, transcludeFn, terminalPriority,
                                replaceDirective && replaceDirective.name, {
                                  // some comments
                                  nonTlbTranscludeDirective: nonTlbTranscludeDirective
                                });
  } else {
     // some code
     childTranscludeFn = compile($template, transcludeFn);
  }
}
```

#### inside `ngRepeat`:

- This directive watches the collection for changes
- On change, It iterates all collection items to find new added items (or removed items)
- It clones the trancluded content to a new child scope for each new item (uses $transclude)

#### A fragment from [ngRepeat source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngRepeat.js):

```
var ngRepeatDirective = ['$parse', '$animate', function($parse, $animate) {
  var NG_REMOVED = '$$NG_REMOVED';
  var ngRepeatMinErr = minErr('ngRepeat');
  return {
    transclude: 'element',
    priority: 1000,
    terminal: true,
    $$tlb: true,
    link: function($scope, $element, $attr, ctrl, $transclude){

        // some code

        $scope.$watchCollection(rhs, function ngRepeatAction(collection){

          // some code

          for (index = 0, length = collectionKeys.length; index < length; index++) {

            // some code

            if (!block.scope) {
              $transclude(childScope, function(clone) {

                // some code

              });
            }
          }

          // some code
        });
    }
  };
```