# Angular JS model changes not reflected in view when ng-repeat and custom directives are combined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following fiddle setup to demonstrate what I am experiencing.

http://jsfiddle.net/BjornJohnson/ndxnG/25/

My controller uses these objects: page => rows => columns => pieces.  A page has rows.  A row has columns. A column has pieces.

There is a custom directive ("piece").  The point of the directive is to be able to provide different types of HTML elements based on the "type" of the piece (so-called dynamic templating).

I keep running into problems when I remove pieces from a column.  I am modifying the model, but it's not reflected in the view.  It works when the ng-repeat is on a wrapper, but not on the custom directive itself, so I think something is clashing with the ng-repeat directive.

I apologize in advance for using all caps, but **I CANNOT USE A WRAPPER DIV FOR THE NG-REPEAT** :)

The code in question is both in the view and the directive.

Here's part of the custom directive:

```
var template = templates[scope.piece.key];
var replacement = $($compile(template)(scope));
element.replaceWith(replacement);
```

Here's part of the view:

```
<div ng-repeat="column in row.data.columns" ng-class="column.data.clss">
   <!-- notice wrapper for ng-repeat - THIS VIOLATES MY REQUIREMENTS -->
   <div ng-repeat="piece in column.data.pieces">
      <piece></piece>
   </div>
</div>
```

*versus...*

```
<div ng-repeat="column in row.data.columns" ng-class="column.data.clss">
   <!-- notice ng-repeat on custom directive -->
   <piece ng-repeat="piece in column.data.pieces"></piece>
</div>
```

Comment: NG-REPEAT is terminal, with a higher priority of 1000, so this would seem to make sense if the custom directive simply did not work at all, but it DOES seem to work.  Just not as expected.

Comment: This question may answer some of this, but I am still curious.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21387827/angularjs-ngrepeat-directive-does-not-have-compile-option

Comment: Exactly what is not working? They behave identically here (or I am missing something?)

Comment: Please try removing the photo of the ninja by hovering and then clicking the orange X control.  In the top example, the view reflects the change to the model.  In the bottom, the view does not reflect the change.  In the source code (in the output, not the fiddle source), you can see a bit what is happening as well.  Thank you.